# Object Moving in Win Forms

Tags: c#

I am using the below code in Windows Forms to move a button. However, the button is flickering when it moves. Even though I'm using SmoothingMode.HighQuality and DoubleBuffer.

How can I reduce the flickering of the button?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.UpdateStyles();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        if (button1.Location.X > 10 && button1.Location.X < 550)
        {
            Point osp = new Point(button1.Location.X + 1, button1.Location.Y);                
            button1.Location = osp;
        }
        else
        {
            Point osp = new Point(11, button1.Location.Y);
            button1.Location = osp;
        }  
     }
```

Comment: Mehmet, I just tried the same code that you posted and it's working for me.
You don't need the repeated "this.DoubleBuffered = true;" in the Tick event handler, though. You already set that up in the Initialization code. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Code is work but object flickers when moving.

Comment: Animating like this is a Really Bad Idea.  Moving the control window requires the parent to repaint itself so it can redraw the space formerly occupied by the control window.  That takes time, double buffering makes it *slower*.  Animate by painting, not by moving controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease the Interval between each tick by using the Timer's Interval property;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Interval = 400;
}
```

Also remove the below piece of code from the **timer1_tick** method since you are already using it in the initialization of the form

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```